# R data.table subset with compare

Tags: r, comparison, data.table, subset

I'm using data.table for fast subsetting. However whan I subset not based on keys equal to a value but smaller than , it takes a lot of time. 
For example:

```
DT["2"]
```

is fast, while

```
DT[key<2]
```

is slow.

I assume the first is a binary search and the second a vector scan, but how to do the second in a fast way?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: `DT[2]` is NOT the same as `DT[key==2]`! And if you really set the key, your second version should be extremely fast.

Comment: I know that `DT[2]` does a binary search(fast), while `DT[key==2]` does a vector scan(slow).
However I get 0.03 seconds for `DT[2]` and 0.5 seconds for `DT[key<2]`. Is it possible to have a fast `DT[key<2]`?

Comment: You need to give more information about your data. How big is the data. Have you set key or not? Btw - `DT[2]` gives second row not the row where `key == 2`

Answer (score 4):

Usually, when you subset on a key column to take advantage of fast binary search based subset, you'd do:

```
DT[J(values)] # assuming subset here is on the first key column.
# (or)
DT[.(values)] # idem
```

Both `.` and `J` here do exactly the same. When your key column is of type `character`, since you also have to quote the character value, `data.table` also allows for a join if possible without the `J` or `.`, for convenience. That is,

```
DT["a"]       # subset on the first key column if one exists
# (or)
DT[J("a")]    # idem
# (or)
DT[.("a")]    # idem
```

This facility is just on character vectors. It's possible because you can't subset a `data.table` using character vector in `i` by any other way. So, it's easy to tell that you're wanting a join. But if you provide `DT[2]`, `2` here being `numeric`, `data.table` can't really tell if you're expecting a *join* or a *normal row-subset*. That's why it's just for characters.

Now, `DT[J(.)]` will be fast because, when the key is set, it's already sorted and therefore we can subset using fast binary search. However, the case `DT[x < .]` uses normal *vector scan* approach. That is, it'll check all the values of `x` for the value `a`, even if the values are sorted by `x`. Therefore, the second one will be slower than the first.

There are feature requests to enable binary search based subset on *ranges*. You've have a look [here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?atid=978&group_id=240&func=browse). Once it's implemented, these things will automatically get faster. We've not gotten to it just yet.

HTH.

PS: Note that you're comparing `DT["2"]` - which is a character key column based binary search subset against `DT[key < 2]` where `key` is numeric here. They're not the same. The equivalent (as I explained above) is `DT[J(2)]`.

Also note that they are not equivalent operations. `DT[J(2)]` looks only for key column that matches `2` in DT, where as `DT[key < 2]` looks for all values in the range `[min[key], 2)`.

Comment: Thanks Arun. I meant to write DT[J(2)].

Meanwhile I thought of a workaround:
`DT[,N:=.I]`
`DT[1:DT[J(2),roll=TRUE][,N]]`

On my database it takes 0.05, instead of 0.5 for `DT[key<2]`

Comment: @misha_dodic, Great! i think this'll also work: `DT[seq_len(DT[J(2), which=TRUE, mult="first"]-1L)]`

Comment: @Arun The hyperlink in the answer is not working. Can you please update it